# Eternal page refresh in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have a method for downloading and receiving news, I'm trying to add an update using RefreshView. I can't determine what the error is. When I try to refresh the page, an eternal loading begins, which does not end with anything
Here is my view:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <RefreshView x:Name="refreshView" RefreshColor="#81b745" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Сообщества" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0,20,0,10" />

                <StackLayout Padding="20">
                    <Label Text="Добро пожаловать в сообщества" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                    <Button Text="Создать сообщество" BackgroundColor="#81b745" Clicked="CreateCommunityPage" TextColor="White" CornerRadius="5" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
                </StackLayout>

                <ListView x:Name="CommunitiesListView" RowHeight="150">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            // Community Display Code  
                        <DataTemplate>    
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Here 's mine .xaml.cs here is an update and methods for getting and loading communities :

```
private bool _isRefreshing;
public bool IsRefreshing
{
    get { return _isRefreshing; }
    set
    {
        if (_isRefreshing != value)
        {
            _isRefreshing = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRefreshing));
        }
    }
}

public ICommand RefreshCommand => new Command(async () => await RefreshDataAsync());

private async Task RefreshDataAsync()
{
    IsRefreshing = true;

    await LoadCommunities();

    IsRefreshing = false;
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    RefreshDataAsync();
}


private async Task<List<CommunityModel>> GetCommunitiesAsync()
{
    List<CommunityModel> communities = null;

    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string apiUrl = "http://192.168.0.14:8000/api/communities";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                CommunityResponse communityResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CommunityResponse>(content);

                if (communityResponse != null)
                {
                    communities = communityResponse.Data;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Ошибка при запросе: {response.StatusCode}");
                string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine($"Содержимое ответа: {responseContent}");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Произошла ошибка: {ex.Message}");
    }

    return communities;
}

private async Task LoadCommunities()
{
    try
    {
        List<CommunityModel> communities = await GetCommunitiesAsync();

        if (communities != null && communities.Any())
        {
            foreach (var community in communities)
            {
                community.MembersCount = await GetCommunityMembersCountAsync(community.Id);
            }

            CommunitiesListView.ItemsSource = communities;
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Не удалось загрузить сообщества", "OK");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", $"Произошла ошибка: {ex.Message}", "OK");
    }
}
```

Comment: have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Did you try to add the `await` for the RefreshDataAsync() method? Such as : `await RefreshDataAsync();`